# Jquery get row value in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Html:**

```
 <tbody id="JusticeCourtTable"></tbody>
```

I load datas to page by below jquery code.I have inputs and buttons as below.

```
 $.getJSON('/CourtHouseManagement/LoadLawCourt/?cityId=' + id, function (result) {

                $('#JusticeCourtTable').html('');

                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                    var tablestring =

                        '<tr>' +
                        '<th>' + result[i].CourtID + '</th>' +
                        '<th><input type="text" name="JusticeCourt" id="JusticeCourt" value="' + result[i].Name + '" class="form-control" data-required="true"></th>' +

'<th><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-process="' + 0 + '" data-courtid="' + result[i].CourtID + '" data-name="' + result[i].Name + '">Update</button></th>' +
'<th><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-process="' + 1 + '" data-courtid="' + result[i].CourtID + '" data-name="' + result[i].Name + '">Delete</button></th>';



                    tablestring += '</tr>';
                    $("#JusticeCourtTable").append(tablestring);
                }
            });
```

I send above inputs values by using below jquery code

```
    $(document).on('click', '#JusticeCourtTable button', function () {
 if ($(this).data('process') == 0) {

                var cityId = id;
                var lawCourtId = $(this).data('courtid');
                var lawCourtName = $(this).data('name');  // PROBLEM HERE



                window.location.href = '/CourtHouseManagement/UpdateLawCourt/?lawCourtId=' + lawCourtId + "&lawCourtName=" + lawCourtName + "&cityId=" + cityId;
            }
    });
```

**My question :**

How can i get value of textbox

```
<input type="text" name="JusticeCourt" id="JusticeCourt" value="' + result[i].Name + '" class="form-control" data-required="true">
```

`var lawCourtName = $(this).data('name');` always gets default value.If i enter a new value , i can not get new value by using this code.How can i get new value for data('name') ?

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: it is a text value , i write a new value. As instance xxx , if i click to button , i must send "xxx" value .

Comment: you need value of textbox which is enterd?

Comment: yes my friend exactly what i need for input

Comment: ``$(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').val()`` use this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the value entered in textbox then you have to do like this:

```
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').val()
```

## Explanation:

get parent tr  using `closest()` and then used `find()` to get the input field in it and get its value

Answer (score 0):

For getting the `textbox` `name` attribute, try like:

```
....
......
var lawCourtName = $('#JusticeCourt').attr('name');//get textbox name
var lawCourtVal = $('#JusticeCourt').val();//get textbox value
.....
...
```